# Creating/accessing indexedDB in two different offline web apps of same domain uses the same database

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, offlineapps

I have created an two  different offline web apps, and each uses IndexedDB to store videos. They are located at different urls but the same domain. For example:

```
http://example.com/first-web-app
http://example.com/second-web-app
```

In both, I create a database called "video_files" and store the videos as "video1", "video2", etc. The code first checks if the video exists in the database, and if so loads it, otherwise writes it in there.

After viewing the first web app in the browser, in the second web app, it finds "video1"! And it loads the video from the first web app!

My questions:

1. Is this the correct spec for IndexedDB? One per domain?
2. Is there a way around this?
3. Will this mean that the restriction on space for an offline web app (e.g. 50 MB on iOS Safari) is a domain-wide restriction, not web app restriction?

CODE:

```
//This somehow returns the same database in both apps
var request = indexedDB.open( "video_files", 1.0 );

//This will load the same video in both apps
var transaction = Video.database.transaction( [ "videos" ], "readwrite" );
var request = transaction.objectStore( "videos" ).get( "video1" );
```

**EDIT: It's not clear there's a limit on storage in IndexedDB for iOS at least** I used this code: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/17/indexeddb-and-limits and was able to store **198MB** before I just simply stopped trying.

Comment: 1. yes. 2. use a different database name per app, maybe the first path segment of location.href. 3. yes, 50mb per domain.

Comment: @dandavis Are you sure about #3? That's a huge restriction issue!

Comment: yeah, just like localStorage, indexDB doesn't care about the page, only the domain. DBs are not designed to hold videos... you can abuse sub-domains for more space...

Comment: @dandavis I understand that, but the size restriction is not an IndexedDB restriction - it's an entire web app restriction applied by the various browsers (and each has different limits). So are you sure it's 50MB total for a domain?

Comment: Just as a clarification, and possibly the basis of a workaround (hack) would be the fact that it is origin, not domain, that is the issue - foo.example.com, bar.example.com, and bar.example.com:3000 are different origins, even though they are all in the same domain.

Comment: @barry-johnson yes, sorry, I meant origin, not domain. But do you know if the size restriction imposed by iOS Safari (and other browsers) is per-origin or per web app?

Comment: whatever they are called, sharding "foo.example.com, bar.example.com, and bar.example.com:3000" would provide 150MB to indexedDB under your 50mb guideline... 50mb is a ton of room, considering we used to have to deal with only cookies!

Comment: @DonRhummy - yes, the limit will be per origin.

Comment: @dandavis Except offline apps with videos can use 150MB very quickly.

Comment: @barry-johnson thank you. Do you know where some documentation on that is?

Comment: @DonRhummy - You're welcome. The spec is at: http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/ - although it definitely reads like a spec - and won't address the idiosyncrasies of various user agents.

Comment: read up about group limits and origin limits at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria  but, i'll say that as much as i love browser-based apps, they really can't do offline video in the scope you're hoping for and packing vids into a DB is going to make cheap phones melt. if you need bulk storage, use cordova.

Comment: @barry-johnson Thanks, but I meant documentation on the size limit per web app for the browsers.

Comment: Sorry - no, there is no real documentation out there on it that I have seen. Raymond Camden did a blog post on desktop Indexed DB limits in which he basically tests them by maxing it out. His findings are at: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/04/17/indexeddb-and-limits - Safari's indexed DB implementation was broken at the time he did it so he didn't test it on that. You can use the web page with script that he has in post to test it on Safari.

Comment: @barry-johnson Using his test page (and my own image of 5MB in size), I was able to store 198MB on iOS 8.4, iPad Air (before I just stopped).

Comment: @DonRhummy - wow - well, maybe that breathes some more life into this alternative for you. Good luck!!!

Answer (score 4):

The trust/security model for the Web platform - including storage APIs (Indexed DB, localStorage, Service Worker Cache, etc) - is *origin* based. Origin = scheme + host + port, so https://example.com, http://example.com, http://example.com:4201 and http://sub.example.com are 4 differerent origins.

If you wish portions of your origin (e.g. pages) to use distinct storage you must partition it yourself, e.g. page1 uses databases prefixed with "page1-" etc. Note that as part of the same origin these pages would have implicit access to other data within the origin.

How browsers assign quota is up to the browser, both in terms of limits and for bucketing. Although http://sub.example.com and http://example.com are different origins and cannot read/write each others's data, it would be acceptable for a user agent to have them both share the same quota.